# Plotting a bit pattern in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I tried plotting the below code, but my plot starts from 1 instead of 0. Can you tell me how I can modify it to start from 0.

```
> % Generate message signal 

> t1 = -1:0.1*pi:1;

> message_sig = rectpuls(t1);

> L = length(message_sig);

> figure(2)

> stairs(message_sig, 'linewidth',1.5);

> axis([0 L -1 2]);

> title('Message Signal');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because in matlab the counting starts from 1. When you just mention one parameter in the plot function, (which in this case it is 'stairs'):

```
stairs(message_sig)
```

since the message_sig variable is a vector ('say [0 0 1 1 1 0 0]'), so the plot function considers the 1st point as 0 so the first point (on X-axis) becomes 1.

Actually, by default it is doing something like this:

```
stairs([1 2 3 4 5 6 7],[0 0 1 1 1 0 0])
```

One solution can be:

```
stairs(0:length(message_sig)-1,message_sig)
```